# Which method is secure for accessing the AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, sdk, aws-cli

Other than AWS Console, there are multiple ways to access the AWS Services.

1. AWS CLI(awscli/AWSPowershell)
2. AWS SDK
3. REST API

Out of these three methods which is the most secure one?

Consider your thinking by the way - If you are working with AWSCLI, you need to store the credentials by using the command `aws configure`.

I know, without passing the credentials(AccessKey and SecretKey) for SDK,CLI and API, we cant access the AWS Services. But I hope still some other way will be there to access/manage the services.

Answer (score 2):

In the end all of these ways call the AWS APIs, so from that perspective they are equally secure.

There are differences in the use of features of the APIs though. While the AWS CLI supports MFA authentication, only some SDKs do (e.g. [`boto3` does](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider), the [`aws-sdk-js` doesn't yet](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1543)) and for accessing the APIs directly you would have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

All of the methods mention have a similar degree of security. Based on how you store and use credentials, might affect the actual security strength.